# Is it a good practice close a socket if we are going to communicate again?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, client-server

I'm coding a Client/server app in java. I came up with an idea that was better to don't close a socket if the server has to communicate again with the client or vice versa. Is it a good practice? In my other apps I always worked with the client connected to the server requesting for the info, now I need something that if some variable is changed in server, the server would have to send that information to some specific client. I don't know how to explain this better. Summing up, how can I send info from server to client without a client request?

Comment: This question is very vague

Comment: @ControlAltDel edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple major problems with trying to connect from a server to a client

1. Non-static IP
2. Firewall & WiFi router configuration
3. Client must be listing

There's more to say on each of these, but suffice it to say that it is much easier if the server maintains the connection from the client, rather than trying to reestablish contact later

Answer (score 1):

You always have to make sure resources are closed as soon as the are not needed anymore.

If you need to wait for requests from the server, you obviously have to keep the socket open, until you actually want to shut the connection down.

Actually, this is how a server works when application protocol allows for several requests to be sent through the same connection. Think of accepting requests initiated by the server as if it were a "server" functionality in the client, but for the fact you are not accepting connections.

Of course, I understand you have a custom application-level protocol. If you work on other application-level protocol, such as HTTP, things may be different. If this is the case, please specify the protocol, so that we can better help you.